# yii2: Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [8] Array to string conversion

Tags: php, soap, yii, yii2

this is my client soap api :

```
         $client = new SoapClient('http://sabapal.ir/sabapal/frontend/web/apit/PaymentRequest?WSDL', array('encoding' => 'UTF-8'));

        $result = $client->PaymentRequest(
                array(
                    'Amount' => 1000,
                )
        );
```

and this is my soap server  :

```
    public function PaymentRequest($Amount)
{

    \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_XML;
    $xmlValues = ['test1' => 'value1', 'test2' => 'value2'];
      return $xmlValues;
}
```

i have this error :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [8] Array to string conversion in /home/sefroweb/domains/sefroweb.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/zarinpal-paid-downloads/zarinpalpaid-downloads.php:2890
```

I do not want to change client soap api

I just want to change `public function PaymentRequest`

Comment: when i returned    return 'aaa'; This problem occurred   : Client] looks like we got no XML document in

Comment: Why you're using `Response::FORMAT_JSON` when you want to send XML?

Comment: I made a mistake when I sent it. The problem was not resolved but I edited it